# Confusing on output result

Tags: c, macros

I just curious why the output is 4 instead of 6 . Any of you can help explain their proccess?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define AMT1 a+a+a
#define AMT2 AMT1 - AMT1
main()
{
int a=1;
printf (“Amount is %d\n”,AMT2);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Ops Sorry , not 6 but 0 because 3-3 . but the output is 4 hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AMT2 = AMT1 - AMT1
AMT2 = a+a+a - a+a+a
AMT2 = 1+1+1 - 1+1+1
AMT2 = 3 -     1 + 1 + 1
AMT2 = 2         + 1 + 1
AMT2 = 3             + 1
AMT2 = 4
```

The first rule of macros is: you need parentheses around everything.  You want:

```
#define AMT2 (AMT1) - (AMT1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Macros like this do literal text replacement. When you compile your code, `AMT2` is literally being replaced by `AMT1`, so you're effectively running:

```c
printf (“Amount is %d\n”,a+a+a - a+a+a);
```

You can verify this yourself by looking at the output of the preprocessor (after the macros have been replaced) by running

```
gcc file.c -E
```

---

To solve your problem, you can either:

1. Make a function instead
2. Put parenthesis around all your macro definitions (this is always recommended)

So your code would look like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define AMT1 (a+a+a)
#define AMT2 (AMT1 - AMT1)

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    printf ("Amount is %d\n", AMT2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you do the macro replacements, the code becomes

```
printf("Amount is %d\n", 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 + 1);
```

Addition and subtraction are left-associative, so the expression is equivalent to

```
((((1 + 1) + 1) - 1) + 1) + 1)
```

If you want the macros to act more like variables, you need to wrap the expansions in parentheses:

```
#define AMT1 (a+a+a)
#define AMT2 (AMT1 - AMT1)
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple

```
AMT2 (AMT1) - (AMT1)
```

and/or

```
AMT1 (a+a+a)
```

should do your work.